# awk split on first occurrence of character

Tags: awk

Trying to use `awk` to split each line. If there is more the one `p` or `q` the second split on the `(` does not work correctly (line 2 is an example. I am not able to ignore the second if there is more then one occurrence. I tried `^pq` but that did not produce the desired. Thank you :).

**file**

```
1p11.2(120785011_120793480)x3   
1q12q21.1(143192432_143450240)x1~2
```

**awk**

```
awk '{split($0,a,"[pq(_]"); print "id"a[1],a[3]}' file
```

**current**

```
id1 120785011
id1 21.1
```

**desired**

```
id1 120785011
id1 143192432
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -F'[(_]' '{split($0,a,"[pq]"); print "id"a[1],$2}' file

id1 120785011
id1 143192432
```

since you don't control the number of `pq`s in the line, use two different splits, one for the field delimiter to find the value, the second for the id.

Answer (score 3):

the `split` function returns the number of fields, so we can take advantage of that:

```
{
    n = split($0, a, /[pq(_]/)
    printf "id%s %s\n", a[1], a[n-1]
}
```

outputs

```
id1 120785011
id1 143192432
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is something you can do using `FS` regex itself and keeping `awk` simple:

```sh
awk -F '[(_]|[pq]([^pq]*[pq])*' '{print "id" $1, $3}' file

id1 120785011
id1 143192432
```

**`FS` regex details**

- `'[(_]`: Match `(` or `_`
- `|`: OR
- `[pq]([^pq]*[pq])*`: Match `p` or `q` followed by 0 or more non-pq characters followed by `p` or `q`

Answer (score 2):

I'd use sed for this since it's simple substitutions on a single line which is what sed is best for:

```
$ sed 's/\([^pq]*\)[^(]*(\([^_]*\).*/id\1 \2/' file
id1 120785011
id1 143192432
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE 1 : realized I could make it even more succinct :

```
mawk 'sub("^","id")<--NF' FS='[pq][^(]+[(]|[_].+$'
```

It works even when there are empty rows embedded in the input because `sub()` went first, so `NF` won't get decremented into negative zone and triggering an error message.

=============================================================

An `awk`-based solution without requiring:

> - further, and *redundant*, `array`-splitting, or
> - a **back-reference**-capable `regex` engine:

```
 input :

1p11.2(120785011_120793480)x3   
1q12q21.1(143192432_143450240)x1~2

 command ::

  mawk 'sub("^","id",$!(NF*=2<NF))' FS='[pq][^(]+[(]|[_].+$' 

 output :

id1 120785011 
id1 143192432
```